# Javascript: 3 attempts game logic

Tags: javascript, css, architecture, logic

I'm building a javascript+css game that shows 3 heart icons representing the 3 attempts the game allows the user to have.

I have 3 types of hearts:

a normal one representing a not used attempt

a highlighted one representing a successful attempt

a crossed one representing a failed attempt

Also I have a variable called "result" that stores 0 (attempt failed) or 1 (attempt successful)

Could you please help me with representing the 3 attempts logic? Meaning changing the heart icons on the screen depending on the user actions.
 I've started by showing the 3 normal hearts that have to show on game start but I don't know how to follow, I'm stuck!

The combinations can be  (being O a normal heart, V a successful attempt heart and X a failed one):

OOO

XOO

VOO

XXO

VXO

XVO

VVO

XXV

XVX

VXV

VXX

VVX

XVV

XXX

VVV

Thanks a million

Comment: Help with what? The logic that decides if the attempt is successful or not? A function that prints the "hearts" on the document? A function that changes them after the user do something? Explain further...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you asking for help changing the icons on the page in response to user actions? Are you asking for help implementing game logic? Your question is really ambiguous about what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: sorry you're right, I've been so many hours on top of it that I cannot think clearly. I have edited the post, but please if you need anymore info, tell me so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at any point, you can represent the state of the hearts using 3 numbers, where each number can be a 1,2 or 3. Lets say 1 represents a normal heart, 2 represents a highlighted heart, and 3 represents a crossed heart.

So you can store the state of the hearts as an integer. At the start of the game, all of the hearts are normal hearts, so:

```
var state = new Array();
state[0] = 1
state[1] = 1
state[2] = 1
```

Now, just keep track of which attempt the user is on using another variable, say `attemptNumber`. So, at the start of the game, `attemptNumber=1`. After the user has finished that attempt, just set `state[attemptNumber]` equal to 2 if the attempt was successful, or 3 if it failed, and then increment attemptNumber by 1. Now, the user only gets 3 attempts, and after the third attempt, `attemptNumber` is equal to 4. So just put the whole game in a while loop like `while (attemptNumber < 4) (play the game)`.

As for the CSS, change the icon for each heart depending on the value of `state`.